# How to use st_geometry_type() to filter an sf object in r?

Tags: r, sf

Put together this code to filter an sf object by geometry type as suggested by @Spacedman [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306720/reading-kml-files-in-r/306800#306800)

Posting here for others and for myself in case there are better ways to do this.

```
types <- st_geometry_type(my_sf_object)

types_df <- data.frame(types)

my_labelled_sf_object <- merge(my_sf_object, types_df,by.x=0, by.y=0, all.x=TRUE)

feature_type <-  "LINESTRING"

# value here can be any of
# GEOMETRY,POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON 
# GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON, MULTICURVE,
# MULTISURFACE, CURVE, SURFACE, POLYHEDRALSURFACE, TIN, TRIANGLE 

my_filtered_sf_object <- labelled_layers[labelled_layers$types %in% feature_type,]
```

this use of `%in%` seems correct but strikes me as very weird syntactically since really I'm selecting only rows with `feature_type` *in* that column rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%in%` is used to match a single value from a vector with *any* of the values *in* another vector. For example this returns `TRUE` if any values on the left are in the set of 2, ,5 or 12:

```
> (1:10) %in% c(2,5,12)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If you are only testing against a single value then you can use `==`, so your example should be equivalent to:

```
labelled_layers$types == feature_type
```

because `feature_type` is just "LINESTRING".

If you want to check against a number of geometry types with the same dimension, eg all linear features:

```
labelled_layers$types %in% c("LINESTRING","MULTILINESTRING")
```